# Show global Message in User Profiles with admin only Input field in Wordpress Backend

Tags: admin, user-roles, user-meta, options, profiles

I try to display a piece of text (without plugin) for example "Quote of the day: Some text" on all user profile pages (.../wp-admin/profile.php).

This Text should managable/editable from the Profile of the ADMIN. In the Admins Profile Page should be a Text Input field where i can change the Text and save.

Since yesterday i was not able to find any hint to achive this. I found a lot of tutorials to create custom User Field for the profile Page - but nothing like i need.

So far i was able to create a text input field where i can save the text (input) in the database and display it only in the admins profile page with:

```
function add_qoute_of_the_day_backend( $user ) { 
// Visible only for admins
if( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) { 
?>
<div class="visible-only-for-admin">
    <h3>Quote of the Day Input Field</h3>
    <table class="form-table" >
        <tr>
            <th><label for="qoute_of_the_day">Qoute of the Day</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="qoute_of_the_day" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta( 'qoute_of_the_day', $user->ID )); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php }
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_qoute_of_the_day_backend', 10 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_qoute_of_the_day_backend', 10 );

function save_qoute_of_the_day_backend( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return false;       
    update_user_meta( $user_id,'qoute_of_the_day', sanitize_text_field ( $_POST['qoute_of_the_day'] ) );
}
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_qoute_of_the_day_backend' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_qoute_of_the_day_backend' );
```

The code above works, but how can i display the input of the admin, in Text Form (just: "Quote of the day: Some Text") in all other user profiles? Maybe any way to create a simple input field just for the admin Role and display the input in all profiles?

**Visual - what im trying to achive:**

INPUT FIELD in the profile page of the admin:

[image]

DISPLAY Text in all other user profiles:

[image]

**Any help would be greatly appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the capability check "inwards":

```
function wpse_230369_quote_of_the_day( $user ) { 
    $quote = esc_attr( get_option( 'quote_of_the_day' ) );
    ?>

<div class="visible-only-for-admin">
    <h3>Quote of the Day Input Field</h3>
    <table class="form-table" >
        <tr>
            <th><label for="quote_of_the_day">Quote of the Day</label></th>
            <td>
                <?php if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) : ?>

                    <input type="text" name="quote_of_the_day" value="<?php echo $quote ?>" class="regular-text" />

                <?php else : ?>

                    <?php echo $quote ?>

                <?php endif ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<?php
}

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'wpse_230369_quote_of_the_day', 10 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'wpse_230369_quote_of_the_day', 10 );

function wpse_230369_save_quote_of_the_day( $user_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['quote_of_the_day'] ) && current_user_can( 'administrator' ) )
        update_option( 'quote_of_the_day', sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['quote_of_the_day'] ) ) );
}

add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'wpse_230369_save_quote_of_the_day' );
add_action( 'personal_options_update',  'wpse_230369_save_quote_of_the_day' );
```

Comment: Hi, it does not echo the $quote in the users profiles...? The Admin part looks fine.

Comment: Are you sure `$quote` has a value.

Comment: Yes - echo $quote returns the input - BUT only in the Profile Page of the admin! (i chceked it) In the Profiles of the other users it does NOT work. Any idea? thx

Comment: Because the quote is stored as a per-user setting?

Comment: Look at the code above `function save_qoute_of_the_day_backend( $user_id ) {...` I have no idea how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Fix what? Can you confirm if this should be a per-user setting or not?

Comment: the goal is, to allow ONLY the admin to change and save the text input and display just the text on all other users profile pages regardless wich user role except the admin.

Comment: Yes, and should the quote be a global quote (same for all users), or do want to be able to set a quote for each user?

Comment: The qoute should be global (same for all users)

Comment: Hi, @TheDeadMedic - any idea how to solve my problem? thx

Comment: If the quote needs to be global, use the options API, not user meta (see update).

Comment: @NewUser Any luck?